# Can I choose some(not all) elements in an array and shuffle it in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, shuffle

Can I choose some elements in an array and shuffle it in PHP? 
You know, when you use

```
shuffle(array)
```

, It shuffles all elements in an array, but I just want to shuffle some elements in an array while keep other elements unchanged, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following

```
function swap(&$a, &$b) { list($a, $b) = array($b, $a); }

$len = count($a);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
   $j = rand(1, $len) - 1;
   swap($a[$i], $a[$j]);
}
```

this is the standard loop that shuffles all array elements. To shuffle only some ("movable") elements, let's put their keys into an array

```
$keys = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17);
```

and replace the loop over $a with the loop over $keys

```
$len = count($keys);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
   $j = rand(1, $len) - 1;
   swap($a[$keys[$i]], $a[$keys[$j]]);
}
```

this moves elements in positions 1, 3, 5 etc. and leaves other elements in place

Comment: I want to shuffle associative array, not numeric array.

Comment: Per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm, you might want to swap from rand($i, $len) rather than rand(1, $len).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_slice` to copy the part of the array you want to shuffle, shuffle the copy, and then use `array_splice` to copy the shuffled data back into the original array.

**EDIT:** More generally, if you know the keys of the items you want to shuffle, put them in an array called `$keys`. Then:

```
// Get out the items to shuffle.
$work = array();
foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
    $work[$i] = $myarray[$key];
}

shuffle($work);  // shuffle them

// And put them back.
foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
    $myarray[$key] = $work[$i];
}
```

*(Sorry if this has some mistakes; my PHP is rusty and I'm not near a computer where I can test it!)*

Something very similar will work for a multidimensional array. Each element of `$keys` could be an array of indices, and instead of `$myarray[$key]` you would write `$myarray[$key[0]][$key[1]]`.

Comment: What if the array is a multidimensional array and I want to shuffle some elements in the second level, not the first level?

Comment: OK, edited it to describe how you would apply this technique to a multidimensional array.